# Exporting SVG files from plots created in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, plot

So I'm trying to export some plots I created using matplotlib and seaborn.

I create my plot with:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plty
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.display import set_matplotlib_formats
set_matplotlib_formats('png', 'pdf')

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheetname='IvT')

sns.set_style("white")
plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
plt.xlabel('Test', fontsize=18)
plt.title ('Test', fontsize=22)
#sns.boxplot(df[['Short total']])
sns.boxplot(df[['Short total']])
plt.show()
```

If I try to export it with

```
matplotlib.pyplot.savefig("test.svg", format="svg")
```

I get an error message saying

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 
>   ----> 2 matplotlib.pyplot.savefig("test.svg", format="svg")
>
> NameError: name 'matplotlib' is not defined

Comment: It's plt.savefig()

Comment: Also, you have imported matplotlib and matplotlib.pyplot as plt. It is usually only the latter which is abbreviated to plt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be overcomplicating the importing of modules. In the code, you have imported `matplotlib` *and* `matplotlib.pyplot` as `plt`. In addition, having already imported `matplotlib.pyplot`, you try and do it again using `from matplotlib import pyplot`

When you try and save your file you have then done `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig`, but you have already imported `matplotlib.pyplot` as `plt`.

The specific error you have shown is because, while you have import `matplotlib` itself, you have imported it **as** `plt`, which is why the error says that `matplotlib` is not defined.

In order to fix this, you need to clean up the imports like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib # if abbreviating this, use "as mpl"
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.display import set_matplotlib_formats
set_matplotlib_formats('png', 'pdf')

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheetname='IvT')

sns.set_style("white")
plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
plt.xlabel('Test', fontsize=18)
plt.title ('Test', fontsize=22)
#sns.boxplot(df[['Short total']])
sns.boxplot(df[['Short total']])
plt.show()
```

Then in order to save your figure use:

```
plt.savefig("test.svg", format="svg")
```

Remember to call this **before** `plt.show()`

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was able to export a svg file but unfortunately it is empty. Any ideas why that happened?

Comment: I know that this might be slightly off topic, but do you know how I can get my boxplot, created with seaborn , from horizontal to vertical?